# After Git VS2013 ReSharper cannot find References. Project builds and runs normally

Tags: git, visual-studio, resharper

After using git checkout several times, VS2013 cannot find references to other projects in same solution. ReSharper shows many errors. However the project builds and runs normally.

I cloned the project again, but no changes. Clean and rebuild do not help.

How to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Try Suspending and resuming Resharper. That usually clears up that mess for me. http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/NETCOM/ReSharper+Tips+and+Tricks

Comment: I already tried it. It's not working.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the Resharper Solution Caches? http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Environment__General.html

Comment: I did, but there was no effect. However I restarted VS now (again) and the resharper rechecked the solution and fixed the errors.

Answer (score 1):

A probable solution: Cleaning ReSharper caches **and restart**.

[image]